# Pass sender as parameter to string.format function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameters

I am trying to pass a custom Eval parameter to a javascript function

```
clientEvents-OnvalueChanged="function(sender,args){ValTicket(sender,args,'<%#Eval("ID")')}"
```

This is what I have, but it says an error that the server tag is not well formed, I know this has to do with the single and double quotes, but if I change them around then the function was just passing the eval as a string, not calculating it

I also tried this:

```
ClientEvents-OnValueChanged='<%# String.Format("ValTicket({0},{1},{2})", sender, EventArgs, Eval("ID"))%> '
```

This gets the right ID, but its not passing sender and args properly

How can I pass a Eval as a custom parameter to a javascript function?